# A DNS issue occasionally preventing access to some websites

Tags: network-manager, dns, dnsmasq

I've begun having this problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10 but it may not related with it: **Now and then, suddenly I cannot access a website which I visit frequently.**
Google Chrome says;

"This site can't be reached ... server DNS address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN"

However, the problem disappears immediately after I restart dnsmasq (`sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart`)

For instance, just some minutes ago this happened with news.google.com although www.google.com was perfectly accessible at the same time.

**A possible temporary workaround:**

Using this (or similar other) Chrome extension and switching to some other DNS server:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browsec-vpn-privacy-and-s/omghfjlpggmjjaagoclmmobgdodcjboh

Comment: Having the exact same issue but I'm on Kubuntu 16.10. Have you solved this yet?

Comment: No luck. I've just looked at `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` for a possible cause, but it only contains to uncommented items: `listen-address=127.0.0.1` and `addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.block` which have been there for a very long time.

Comment: For me YouTube seems to go out the most.  Google always seems to work.  But there is particular domains that don't work.  It's very strange.  I know that when it happens my Windows 10 VM works so I know it's related to Ubuntu.